# vb net SQl query problem

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im trying to retrieve some data using a reader in vb.net. I dont have any issue retrieving certain columns of the data for each row but i want to retrieve all data in each row. I've tried a couple of different things with the getstring() command but it isnt working and i cant seem to find any help googling the issue. my code is this

```
Private Function QueryDown(ByVal queryString)
    Dim returnInfo As New StringBuilder
    Try
        Dim newQuery As String() = Split(queryString, ":")
        For Each Query In newQuery
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, connection1)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                For a = 0 To reader.FieldCount
                    Dim strng As String = reader.GetString(a)
                    returnInfo.Append(strng & ",")
                Next

                returnInfo.Append(";")
            End While
            reader.Close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        console("Error with MySQL: " & ex.Message)
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
    Return returnInfo.ToString
End Function
```

sorry the error i get when using this code is

> *There is already an open DataReader
>   associated with this Connection which
>   must be closed first*

but if i change `getstring(a)` to `getstring(1)` everything is fine, im confused.
any help here would be great, i want to formatted code to come back column,column,coloumn;nextrow, as you can see (i hope). Because each of my table has a different amount of coloumns and i want to be able to use the same function for each one. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper limit is `reader.FieldCount - 1` not `reader.FieldCount` in:

```
For a = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
```

when `a` reaches `reader.FieldCount` there is an exception => `reader.Close()` is not executed => I suppose you call this function (or another) to open a new reader with the same connection => error.

When you call `getstring(1)` its working because `1` is within `[0, FieldCount-1]`

### Update:

As *@Zach Green* said, try to always use `using` when ever possible which is a replacement for `try...finally{ .Dispose() }`: the dispose in `finally`is applied to `object beeing "used"` and calling for `DataReader/DataConnection` it will call `.Close()` for you.

Comment: you are the man sir, thank you very much. i feel like a retard for not realized that though.....whoops.

Comment: You should be executing your queries by utilizing the 'using' statement to make sure your reader is properly closed on exception: http://weblogs.asp.net/joseguay/archive/2008/07/22/ensure-proper-closure-amp-disposal-of-a-datareader.aspx

Comment: don't worry, it happens to the best of us ;)